# Hide API key using a proxy layer?

Tags: node.js, api-key

I would like to hide my API key. 
My Javascript code makes multiple requests to an external service in the following way:

`api-service.com/file?access_key=<KEY_VALUE>`

hence the key is exposed in the source code / Network tab in the dev console.

I know I can add an IP restriction to allow the key to be used only by my-domain.com, this way if someone pokes into my code he/she can grab the key but not use it in their-domain.com,
however the hacker can use my key on a dev machine (localhost) and use up all my quota.

I want to put a proxy layer between my front-end code and the external service.
So the flow will be:

**Request**:

*frontend (my-domain.com) -> proxy -> external service*

**Response**:

*external service -> proxy -> frontend*

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What exactly are you struggling with? What are the problems you encountered. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sure, so stand up an Express proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to do that would be to have an API route on your site that forwards the request

Assuming the service endpoint/query is
`service.com/api/[...]?access_key=<KEY_VALUE>`

Then you'd have a matching endpoint behind your user auth:
`mysite/api/service1/[...]`
which appends the API key and calls `service.com/api/[...]?access_key=<KEY_VALUE>` and returns that response from your API call.

However that forces you to accept the data on your server and manually send it back. I would love a solution to this which avoids pulling the response down to my server.